# passport.js (github strategy) stops passing along the user to login/success if not on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, github, passport.js

I have an FE: react (localhost:3000) and a BE: node/express server (localhost:8000). I've implemented Passport.js with github-strategy to auth my users. Locally, everything works great.

I deployed to heroku and the user is no longer being passed along in login/success. Now I was not prepared to leave it at "it's heroku's fault!" so I reverted everything back to localhost and put the BE behind an ngrok. Well, it fails in exactly the same way.

To be clear:

1. if I access the server via localhost, it works, but via ngrok it fails.
2. passport auth is successful, no errors, but the user object is gone in the final redirect.
3. In handleLoginSuccess, `req.session` exists but `req.user` does not.
4. I diffed the two session objects, and it looks like the cookie is stripped away when the server is not accessed via localhost directly.

```
passport.use(
  new GitHubStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const user = (await db.getDocument("staff", { githubHandle: login })) || {};
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, { githubHandle: login });
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  if (user) {
    done(null, user);
  } else {
    done(new Error("Failed to deserialize an user"));
  }
});

// ROUTES
router.get("/github", passport.authenticate("github"));
router.get(
  "/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("github", {
    successRedirect: CLIENT_HOME_PAGE_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/auth/login/fail",
  })
);
router.get("/login/success", handleLoginSuccess);
router.get("/login/fail", handleLoginFail);
router.get("/logout", handleLogout);
```

```
const handleLoginSuccess = async (req, res) => {
  // once in this function, the user is available if the server
  // is accessed via localhost, but not via heroku, ngrok. :(
  const user =
    req.user && req.user._id
      ? (await db.getDocument("students", { _id: req.user._id })) ||
        (await db.getDocument("staff", { _id: req.user._id }))
      : req.user;
  res.status(200).json({
    status: user && user.githubId ? 200 : 403,
    success: true,
    user,
  });
};
```

**server.js**

```
const server = require("http").createServer(app);

require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const { checkAuth } = require("./endpoints/auth");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
};

// socket.io
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: corsOptions,
});

app
  .use(helmet())
  .use(morgan("dev"))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(express.json({ limit: "10kb" }))
  .use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  .use(
    cookieSession({
      name: "ca_session",
      keys: [process.env.COOKIE_KEY],
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
    })
  )
  .use(cookieParser())
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())
  .use(cors(corsOptions))
  .use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.io = io; // mind blown
    next();
  })

  // routes
  .use("/auth", require("./routes/auth-routes"))

// ...
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Comment: I don't have a proxy set up, at least not intentionally. I have added the relevant part of my server.js file to the question (If that helps)